# TFS 2015, how to set Agent.BuildDirectory to use _work\1 only

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have setup TFS 2015 with some power shell scripts to change the web.config  on the build definition during the build.

I am faced with the following issue:

1. In the ps script it is hard coded to use "E:\TfsBuildAgents\TfsbuildAgentName_work\1\s\Projects\ProjectName\ProjectName\web.config

I have set the Demands on the Build to Agent.Name = TfsbuildAgnetName (this works well because I want to use one agent name to have the ability to queue the builds as appose the having them run at the same time, but during the queue the one definition uses _work\1 and the second one (which waits for the other to complete) uses _work\2.

Is there anyway I can force the work dir to be 1 on separate build definitions?

Along with Agent.Name, I have tried to use Agent.BuildDirectory and specify _work\1 but the build breaks on the following:

No agent found in pool 12 which satisfies the specified demands:
Agent.Name -equals TfsbuildAgnetName 
Agent.BuildDirectory -equals E:\TfsBuildAgents\TfsbuildAgnetName_work\1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make your scripts more flexible and use a path relative to the script itself leveraging the [`$PSScriptRoot`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Automatic_Variables) variable?

Or even better use the [`$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY`](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/variables) environment variable?

Comment: I have done a bit of a work around for the time being by having a bat file trigger a scheduled task. But your suggestion makes it a lot easier.